# Destroy a specific Armor Stand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to destroy a specific armor stand but when I try the command `/kill @e[type=armor_stand,c=1,r=40]` it just marks the `r=40` and `c=1` in red. When I try to insert the coordinates of the armor stand and place a second one near it, the command block destroys both. I don't want to destroy every single one armor stand on the map because I got lots of them here. So if anyone has an idea please tell me. By the way, I don't have any plugins installed. Playing on 1.15.1.

Comment: Which version are you playing? That command syntax was last correct in 1.12.2, two years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kills the nearest armour stand in Minecraft 1.13 to 1.16:

```
/kill @e[type=armour_stand,sort=nearest,limit=1]
```

Comment: Thank you! Helped me so much. When I had to destroy one I alwys had to destroy all. Thanks again!